# Connecting Twilio SMS to my phone via XMPP

Tags: ios, sms, xmpp, chat, twilio

I'd like to interact with my customers via texting/messaging on a phone app, but not use my personal phone number. Although this seems like a common need, haven't found a solution for that yet.

Twilio SMS services are amazing. I'd like to take advantage of those services as well as utilize a familiar iMessage like interface for interaction with in and out SMS/MMS messages.

Was wondering if I could avoid re-inventing the wheel by using a standard XMPP iOS app with a standard XMPP chat server and only build an intermediate service that would translate between Twilio SMS and XMPP.

I've got to assume that other's have already solved this problem. I'd would love to hear your input on using this approach or hearing how you've solved this.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I am not an expert in XMPP I'm afraid. However, a bit of Googling turned up the following links:

- [SMS over XMPP with Twilio](https://github.com/mndrix/sms-over-xmpp)
- [Multi channel chat with Twilio and Google App Engine](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2013/08/multi-channel-chat-with-twilio-and-google-app-engine.html)
- [Cloudpipes Twilio XMPP integration](https://www.cloudpipes.com/integrations/twilio/xmpp)

Perhaps one of those might help?

Comment: Thank you for these interesting links. I've explored each. I've also learned that Twilio has SMPP in the works. That, I believe, will be the ticket.   

By the way, Cloudpipes, one of the more immediately usable options above, no longer has a Twilio XMPP integration (that I could find).

Comment: Again, I appreciate your input. I just wonder if I'm approaching this problem blindly.      From my perspective, connecting internal staff to external customers on phones via a chat/IM session seems like a common business problem. There are plentiful SMS gateway providers with REST APIs (like Twilio). There are numerous XMPP clients for desktop and smartphones. But there seems to be a scarcity of tools/services/providers that enable the bridge between the two. Besides building a new service or software, do you know of an existing working approach?

Comment: Personally, I am not aware of an existing approach. As I said, I don't really deal with XMPP myself. Good luck finding something though. Perhaps someone else will be able to answer this question and help.

Answer (score 0):

This XMPP component connects Twilio SMS and voice to XMPP: https://wiki.soprani.ca/TwilioSetup

Answer (score -1):

I posted an Android SMS app called Owl SMS, that allows you to do what you wanted, keep your personal SMS (from your mobile phone number) separate from your business SMS. At this time, it only does text, I haven't added MMS.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tigerfarmpress.owlsms&hl=en